# "disabling" (gray text, no mouse/keyboard) jQuery UI widgets and regular HTML inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have an application with many forms which contain checkboxes that disable sections of the form when unchecked. To make these forms easier to maintain, I'd like to create a single method which I can use to "disable" a container (e.g. a DIV containing form UI), where "disable" means:

1. all form input fields are disabled (using the HTML `disabled` attribute)
2. all text is "diabled" by turning it gray (#999)
3. no elements (especially jQuery widgets like tabs) will respond to keyboard or mouse input

For #1, I'm using jQuery to apply the `disabled` attribute to every `input`, `select`, and `textarea`. Easy.

For #2, I'm applying a CSS class (`.disabled {color:#999 !important}`) to the container. For my own controls (e.g. link buttons), I'm adding extra CSS rules to handle extra disabling actions, like turning backgrounds a different color like real buttons do.

But for jQuery UI widgets, is there a generic way to "disable" them so I won't have to build separate CSS classes and/or script to handle disabling each different kind of widget? For example, can I apply a particular class or call a specific method to disable any kind of jQuery UI widget which follows the jQuery UI coding standards?

I'm also stuck on #3. What's a generic way to prevent HTML inside a container from responding to any keyboard or mouse input, especially including jQuery UI widgets?

Answer (score 3):

I created a jquery widget to do just that. I just put it on Github. I am using it in an application where I work and it is doing great. 
You're free to try it out if you'd like.  (  http://dougestep.com/dme/jquery-disabler-widget ).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the widget factory, used as the basis for all jQuery UI widgets, at least tries to bake in some [disabled support](http://jqueryui.com/demos/widget/) that you can use like so:

```
$(dialogEl).dialog("disable");
```

The base functionality [adds the `ui-state-disabled` class and the `aria-disabled` attribute](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L315), and [doesn't fire any handlers](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L350).

It's possible some widgets don't override this correctly for their particular cases; you'd need to test. But it seems likely this will work in most cases.

---

Alternatives:

You might get some mileage out of applying the [`ui-state-disabled`](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API) class, but it will likely only work for styling, and not prevent any response.

One way of preventing responses in some browsers is `pointer-events: none`, but that's [not cross browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events) and kind of a hack (for example, not sure if it has the keyboard behavior you want).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to put an invisible overlay on top of everything that has onclick and onmouseover events that just return false. It can be somewhat awkward, but it's certainly the most effective.